# Max identifier length

Tags: c

Where can I find what is the maximum identifier length in C?

**In which header file is that limit specified?**

Comment: Why would you wish to use so long identifiers that this matters?

Comment: @Tronic, in C89 you're limited to 6 significant characters for external identifiers.

Comment: @tronic Also identifier names upwards of thirty characters come up often enough once developers start to realize the long-term advantages of very semantically clear names and the long-term disadvantages of abbreviations in names.

Comment: @mtraceur My experience exactly. I implement some decently complex stochastic models. The notions are complex enough without us using shorthands and abbreviations everywhere in our naming. Or not specifying what things are meant _for_ , beyond what they _are_, or where they can be used, or where they are valid.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is no header file to contain the identifier length limit; even if there were, how could it help you?  You can't change your identifier lengths at compile time based on a value in a header file anyway.

The [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/), section 5.2.4.1 says:

> - 63 significant initial characters in an internal identifier or a macro name (each universal character name or extended source character is considered a single character)
> - 31 significant initial characters in an external identifier (each universal character name specifying a short identifier of 0000FFFF or less is considered 6 characters, each universal character name specifying a short identifier of 00010000 or more is considered 10 characters, and each extended source character is considered the same number of characters as the corresponding universal character name, if any)

It also contains a footnote:

> Implementations should avoid imposing fixed translation limits whenever possible.

So you should check your documentation to see if your compiler supports a greater number of significant characters in identifiers.

Comment: In which header file is that limit specified?

Comment: It is not in a header file, it is in your compiler's documentation.  Identifiers disappear at runtime.

Comment: @Devel, there is no such thing.  Even if there were, how would it help you?  You can't change your identifier lengths based on a header file, can you?

Comment: you could imagine some macro preprocessing building identifiers in one way or the other depending on the length limit.  It also could be used in code generation.

Comment: I have no idea what that paragraph means in practice. It 32 letters, but then goes into `char` length meanings. What is a _universal character name_ for instance? If I use an entity that compiles to 10 characters, does that mean I really just have room for 3 letters? When does this happen? Chinese?

Comment: @oligofren - this is a reference to the identifiers themselves, not the variables they represent. What are you trying to get at?

Comment: I got that :-) The paragraph starts with talking of a 31 character identifier length for external identifiers. That's normally equivalent to 31 ASCII letters, but the rest of the paragraph uses some (to me) unknown terms like _universal character name_. What is that? Something like a multi-byte Unicode character?

Comment: A "universal character name* is described in 6.4.3. It's using the hex form `\Uxxxxxxxx` to describe characters that aren't in the basic character set.

Comment: Wow this is an old question/answer. My 6.4.3 reference above is from C11. Hopefully stuff didn't move around too much. =)

Comment: @AProgrammer If you can have long or short identifiers, why would you want to use either one depending on what some compiler can do, why not always using the short ones? Name conflicts? But you will have to deal with those also in case the platform only supports short identifiers. For completely generated code, add a random 32 bit hex value at the end of each identifier with underscore. It consumes 9 out of 31 characters and the chance for a collision is 1 to 4 billion and it will only play a role, if the entire rest of it conflicts as well (very unlikely).

Comment: @Mecki Because it is useful and valuable for a library to provide all the benefits of long identifiers for the vast majority of users who have a C implementation that can handle them, and to leave short identifiers (and the problems that come from them) for just the users who have to deal with them.

Comment: I would otherwise +1 this, but I have to -1 purely for the "how could it help you? You can't change your identifier lengths at compile time". Because 1) it can be done, for example by choosing function names using preprocessor conditionals like `#if [name of hypothetical macro defined in header file holding the external identifier length limit] > 6`, and 2) telling people something false or wrong is obviously slightly harmful.

Answer (score 11):

There is no header that tells you.  You have to make an informed decision based on the platforms to which you are likely to be porting.  Carl Norum pointed out what the C99 standard says.

Once upon a time, you could only rely on 6 unique characters, mono-case, for external variables - because that was what some mainframe environments provided.  (This is what the C89 standard said - but it noted that the limitation was painful.)

These days, in part because of type-safe linkage in C++, you can reasonably rely on much longer names for external symbols.  If you start drifting above 31 characters, you may run into problems - but you are also running into readability problems too.

Answer (score 6):

Since there are some bizarre corner cases where it is helpful to have code aware of the limit, here is a method that can be placed in a (albeit hideous to look at) header file:

```
#define SOMEREALLYREALLY...REALLYLONGNAME 1
#if SOMEREALLYREALLY
#define MAXIDENT 16
#elif SOMEREALLYREALLYR
#define MAXIDENT 17
#elif SOMEREALLYREALLYRE
#define MAXIDENT 18
...and so on
```

Eventually, the #ifs will either hit truncated identifier, or the full identifier if the compiler doesn't truncate

Answer (score 3):

In short, no header file exists to tell you that, that is part of a ANSI/ISO C Standard specifications which defines the layout of the syntax and environment mechanism for the C language itself. In pre C89 standards, the maximum identifier length was 6, due to the small memory footprints and environment on such systems such as mainframes and *nix systems.

Today, the latest standard is C99 standards which dictate that the maximum length for an identifier is to be 32, the reason is quite simple and logical...the compiler works by parsing the input stream which would be passed as a command line argument, makefile, or a solution (for Microsoft Visual Studio environments), the parser is rigid and fixed and hence the imposed restrictions on the length of the identifier so that the parser can look ahead and see if there's any more characters. It's down to that reason for it.

Another reason is that most C++ compilers use name mangling on the identifiers which, as Jonathan Leffler pointed out, could confuse the compiler and also the linkage of the code.

Comment: What C99 said was a bit more complicated than 'maximum length is 32'.  See the quote in [Carl Norum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116908/carl-norum)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2352218/15168).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you really want is *a macro* which you can check with `#if` or `#ifdef` to decide how long of identifiers to use.

The macro you want is `__STDC_VERSION__`, which was first defined in C99 (if you want to be more sure that an older compiler isn't defining that macro for some reason, then instead of `#ifdef __STDC_VERSION__` you could do `#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L`).

C99 is also the same standard that raised the minimum lengths of identifiers that C compilers were supposed to support. For example, 32 instead of 6 characters for the minimum that an external identifier was supposed to handle.

But I encourage you to remember that first of all, names are an API and sometimes even ABI surface! So maybe don't change names based on properties of the compiler! If I write code that uses your library, and you made your library change names like that, I have to immitate your test for label size. Now my code has to have a bunch of preprocessor directives selecting different names!

Normally, you should change it based on a macro that your *users* (other developers and people building from source) are able to define if they need compatibility with an ancient compiler or system with such limits.

So it's often better to pick a clear macro name like `MYLIBRARY_SHORT_NAMES`, and `#ifdef` or `#if` for that. Document it in your documentation, perhaps in a "portability" section, for the vanishingly small number of users who will need short names. Document the minimum significant characters needed for the normal names, and for the short names, and let your users figure it out from there in the rare case that they need to.