# What is the max. value of a double/float on iOS?

Tags: ios, c, objective-c, double

What are the values of a double/float on iOS, or the file that they're defined in? Or a macro, like INT_MAX?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

I believe it's in `<float.h>`: `FLT_MAX`, `DBL_MAX`, etc.

Comment: because DOUBLE_MAX would be too difficult to remember...  -_-

Comment: @HerrGrumps In olden days, identifiers had to be unique in the first 8 characters, so `DOUBLE_MAX` would be the same as `DOUBLE_MIN`, which would be awkward.

Comment: Actually it was 6 (case-insensitive) characters AFAIK, so the `X` was even not necessarily considered but `DBL_MA` vs `DBL_MI`. Somehow scary :) See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352209/max-identifier-length

Answer (score 12):

On the iOS simulator, I logged `LONG_MAX`, `FLT_MAX` and `DBL_MAX`. Here's what I got:

```
long max value: 9223372036854775807
float max value: 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000
double max value: 179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.000000
```

Side note, if you use `NSNumber` it uses the appropriate type to store your number.

Answer (score 4):

If you need max value for `CGFloat` you should use safely defined `CGFLOAT_MAX`.