# Why the heavy use of abbreviation in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c

I've been reading up on C and C++ lately and can't help shake the feeling that C/C++ programmers use abbreviation way to excessively in variable and function names. I can't see a reason why this would be beneficial, since both are compiled languages. Practically all code I've come across uses abbreviation more than in other languages (my personal experience, of course).

So the question then becomes this; is there a reason why you'd want to use abbreviations in C/C++? Are there performance issues with using longer variable names, or is it just a convention?

EDIT: Looks like I opened a can of worms here. I was hoping for a yes/no answer, not a discussion on coding style.

Comment: Yes, it's all about programmer performance, and the less they have to type, the faster they code. ;-)

Comment: It's just preference. Some likes to  type less. I myself want explanatory names. It's matter of taste only.

Comment: C/C++ is not a language. But you said it, it is all down to personal experience. Currently I am dealing with a C++ code-base where names are infuriatingly and unnecessarily long.

Comment: "Practically all code I've come across uses abbreviation more than in other languages" -- read some J or APL. Also be aware that it doesn't necessarily have to do with the language so much as the people using it. Academic scientists and mathematicians who become programmers have been trained using single-letter names for everything. Einstein's famous equation is not `energy_in_joules == mass_in_kg * vacuum_speed_of_light_in_meters_per_second * vacuum_speed_of_light_in_meters_per_second`. They are unlikely to see abbreviation as a problem until their scope names more than 26 entities.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young If the speed you code is limited by how many characters you have to type, you aren't thinking enough about what you're doing.  Or you never learned to type (which is inadmissible for a programmer).

Comment: Because some programmers obviously believe, the shorter and harder to read the source code is, the faster the compiled executable will run.

Comment: @JamesKanze I totally agree, of course. I just wanted to write a cheeky answer. :-)

Comment: @juanchopanza The longest names I've seen were in C++.  Over 120 characters.  The programmer who did this was a bit special in other ways, too, and hardly typical of C++ programmers I have known, but it does indicate that short names in C++ aren't an absolute rule.

Comment: Why doesnt this question include all the other languages where people use abbreviations too?

Comment: That would be a way to unconstructive and open question. This was a question about whether abbreviations cause performance issues in C and C++.

Comment: I can only assure you C and C++ programmers ridicule Java developers for their verbosity. Somehow we find the `++` operator more elegant than writing `.getVariableValueAndIncrementItByOneAfterwards();`

Comment: @Oskar: the question is "why the heavy use of abbreviation?" and "is there a reason why you'd want to abbreviate?", as well as "are there performance issues?". If you want a yes/no answer from an eclectic and enthusiastic audience, then you need to ask a yes/no question, not ask any other questions, and not include judgements in your question that someone will disagree with ("way too excessively"). And even then you'd be lucky :-)

Comment: Ah, well, I got the answer I was looking for, so I'm happy.

Comment: I dont think this is a Cpp problem, I think it is a C programmer problem. And it is a problem. Abbreviating words aint bad all the time. Ones like var, obj, i, it, iter, val are so common and intuitive. Also operString() is not a bad abbreviation for getOperatorString(). But look at the code written by Fam Trinli in his youtube video create 16 games using SFML; namely the Chess board game example. All of his names are one or two characters. Furthermore the names are just reference, not abbreviations.  Then check this name, STK_OFS. What you think that means? Wouldn't STACK_OFFSET be better.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's mainly a convention.

There was some historic need, since early C compilers didn't guarantee that identifiers were significant to more than  8 (or maybe even 6) characters in some cases (causing `MyFantasticFoo` and `MyFantasticBar` to be considered equal by the compiler). Modern compilers don't have such tight limitations, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2352218/28169) for details.

Today, I think it's more of a convention/style issue, that C code is often terse.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Interesting, indeed!

Answer (score 9):

It's a hangover from the early days of programming -  before it was realized that the difficult part of programming is not writing code, but reading it.

Comment: I'd like to add that while people learning to program may have a preference to type less, historically they likely weren't using a Code Editor which would pop up function names and variable names as they were typed.  Also, resource limitations (namely memory limits, e.g. MS-DOS's software-based limit of "conventional memory") led to many programs designed to be resource-light, so if there were fewer variables overall then there may have been less perceived need/benefit to using long variable names that help remind people of their purpose.

Answer (score 5):

First, I don't think it's a general rule; as Steve Jessop
reminds us in a comment, other languages, such as APL,
traditionally use even shorter names, and Fortran (at least when
I used it) limited the maximum name length to six.

More than the language, I think the domain plays a role.  For
example, Unix programmers tend to use shorter names than Windows
programmers, doubtlessly because the system API uses shorter
names (partially, at least, because Unix is a lot older, and
earlier linkers couldn't handle more than six or eight
symbols—although that doesn't explain `creat` instead of
`create`).  Mathematics also has a tradition for shortening
names: using names like `index`, rather than `i` for an index
when dealing with mathematical expressions makes the code *less*
clear and explanitory, since the traditional symbol for the
first index in math is `i`.  And many other domains have more or
less established acronyms or abbreviations: when I was working
in telecoms, the specifications doc (from the client) spoke of
TP's and CX's, rather than termination points and cross
connections; and in my current banking environment, even outside
of a program, no one would write "credit default swap" or
"collateralized debt obligation" rather than simple CDS or CDO.
So if you're seeing shorter names in C++, it may be because
you're looking at code which does different things, and comes
from a domain where abbreviations are usual even outside of the
programming environment.