# Maximum length of class name in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

what is the maximum length of a class name in `objective-c`? I could not find any hints in the xcode doc-sets and google was no help either.

I am currently writing some runtime helpers, and it would be nice to know if my char-buffers for the type-encoding are big enough.

Comment: Char buffers?  Why not use a string object like `NSString` or `std::string` and avoid the issue entirely?

Comment: @trojanfoe because i wanted to avoid, propably unnecessary, dynamic memory allocation

Comment: At the cost of functionality?

Comment: @trojanfoe if there was a hard limit and the limit is low, this would be no cost in functionality.

Comment: Is it the time it takes to allocate the memory you are worried about or the amount of memory consumed?  If it's the latter then a fixed-sized buffer is a bad choice.  Consider you make the buffer 64-chars long and most class names are say 8-24 characters, then you are wasting more than 40 bytes per class.  Using a string object consumes (pretty much) exactly the amount of memory required, and you don't restrict the length of the class name, as you would with a fixed-length buffer.

Comment: @trojanfoe its rather the time allocating memory in a big loop. I usally try to avoid unnecessary cpu-work in my core classes just for the benefit of leaner code. But as it seems there is no upper bound for class-names i will use `std::string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Objective C is not a standardized programming language this question can't really be answered. But it rather depends on what your compiler supports. I guess the major Objective C compilers (Clang/LLVM, GCC) support all lengths of class names. To find out you would have to have a look at their sources. But since they are both written in C++ they will probably utilize std:string and be therefore length independent.

I gave it a try and tried to compile a project with a 100.000 character class name using clang/llvm in Xcode, which worked perfectly fine.

So your buffers are likely not to be big enough.

Comment: Thx for your answer, i will use `std::string` instead of a static buffer now.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a hard limit to the class name size, why would there be?

With Obj-C being run on top of C, it would follow their standards. Identifiers in C do not have a maximum length, as identified in the question "[Max identifier length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352209/max-identifier-length)"

It is very unlikely for you to come across a class name greater than 100 characters, but you could always have bigger buffers to be safer.