# Is length of variable name can create any performance or efficiency related issue?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, variables, naming-conventions

I'm working on an `iOS` project with `Objective-C` and I found following line of code written by the someone else previously

```
NSString * const number_of_time_user_open_app_after_last_time_invitation_screen_shown_to_user = @"number_of_time_user_open_app_after_last_time_invitation_screen_shown_to_user";
```

My question is not specific to `Objective-C` or above line of code, I just want to know length of variable can create any performance or efficiency related issue to program or not.

Comment: That depends on whether you consider maintainer sanity to be included in your performance and efficiency metrics or not.

Comment: No, but there is a [maximum length for identifiers in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352209/max-identifier-length), which your rather silly name exceeds. (Long variable names don't make the code clearer. For example, your variable is called `number_of_something`, yet it is a string.)

Comment: You should know that C, C++ and Objective-C are three *totally* different languages, with their own rules and behaviors. That they share much syntax and are partially inter-operable is irrelevant when it comes to how programs in the different languages behave.

Answer (score 0):

Length of variable name doesn't make any difference in performance.

variable occupies some byte of memory base on language compiler. that memory is only refer object which assign to it or data value if it refer to datatype value.